# How to bind click event in template of Kendo?

Tags: javascript, angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I am using treelist component of Kendo. Here, just like most of the other component's of kendo, if we want to render some HTML along with data, we specify those elements in the `template` property. The html written here is in string. 
Ex:

```
template: `<button>#: data # </button>`;
```

However, if I have to attach an angular event along with html, I can't do so since angular compiler doesn't seem to read angular properties in string. I can however attach an event listener explicitly using `addEventListener('click',function())` of `ElementRef` class given by angular but I want to send data as parameter along with the event which is not possible in this method.
Here is what I am trying to acheive:

```
template: `<button (click)="onClickFunction()">#: data # </button>`;
```

How do I acheive the above?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using the jQuery Kendo TreeList and not the Angular Kendo TreeList component?

Comment: because kendo hasn't release treelist for angular

Comment: Sorry, I meant TreeView. Doesn't the [Kendo Angular TreeView](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/treeview/) suit your needs?

Comment: Anyway, in the mean time try using the regular `onclick` event: `template: '<button onclick="onClickFunction()">#: data # </button>';`. It's not an Angular event and it should work.

Comment: I tried it but it says cannot find onClickFunction but I have defined it in my component class

Comment: And what about the TreeView?